# How to keep 'Absent' text in the place of 'Empty' cell base on Current HeaderName Date in gridview row data bound

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, webforms

Trying cell value should be 'Absent' if cell is empty base on headertext date less than and equal to today date that cell should empty, below 12,13 dates are matching with below condition but how to cell field absent base on header text date, header condition is matching with below if condition but not getting how to keep absent.

```
 protected void gridview_trainees_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridView gridView = (GridView)sender;
            var colCount = gridview_trainees.Columns.Count;
            for (int i = 3; i < colCount; i++)
            {
                BoundField columField = (BoundField)((DataControlFieldCell)e.Row.Cells[i]).ContainingField;
                DateTime CurrentColumndate = DateTime.Parse(columField.HeaderText);


                if (CurrentColumndate.Date <=DateTime.Now.Date)
                {
                    //trying cell value should be absent if cell is empty base on header
                }

            }


        }
    }
```

My current gridview is like below

[image]

I want ouput like this, if header text date <= today date that column empty cell should be 'Absent'

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't typically use the default `GridView` and this may not be the best approach but I suspect that since there's no way to directly retrieve the `CellIndex` based on the Cell's HeaderRow value, it's easier to make a list of the `CellIndex` values that match the date criteria.

Then iterate through that list to conditionally change text in cells where the `Cell.Text` value matches the empty criteria.

Add a page property:

```
private List<int> ColIndexes = new List<int>();
```

This is my proposed solution based on a similar situation:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var row = e.Row;
    if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        foreach(TableCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            if(DateTime.TryParse(cell.Text, out var date))
            {
                if(date <= DateTime.Now.Date)
                    ColIndexes.Add(row.Cells.GetCellIndex(cell));
            }
        }
    }

    if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach (var index in ColIndexes)
        {
            var cell = row.Cells[index];
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.Text))
                cell.Text = "Absent";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check my output requirement for last column cells are empty because its future date. @Daniel

Comment: I actually missed that @mohdmazharkhan, I've edited it, please try it again

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan did my answer help you? If so, please accept it